# Is Seebeck coefficient for a metal related to Fermi level as it is the case for contact potential?

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-potential, thermoelectricity, fermi-energy

When putting together two different metals a so called "contact potential" will be built up. So far I understand this is because the combined system wants to reach an equilibrium where free energy is minimized, so the electrochemical potential $\mu$ must be the same under equilibrium: $\mu_1=\mu_2$ Since

$$\mu = \bar{\mu}+e\Phi $$

we get

$$\mu_1 = \bar{\mu_1}+e\Phi_1$$
$$\mu_2 = \bar{\mu_2}+e\Phi_2$$

yielding

$$0 = \bar{\mu_2}+e\Phi_2- \bar{\mu_1}-e\Phi_1$$

and finally

$$\Phi_2-\Phi_1= \frac{1}{e} \left(\bar{\mu_1}-\bar{\mu_2}\right)$$

But how is this related to the Seebeck effect, when the two sides 1, 2 are at different temperatures?

I tried to generalize above to

$$\mu_1(T) \approx \bar{\mu_1}(T=T_0)+ \frac{d \bar{\mu_1}}{dT} \cdot (T-T_0) + e\Phi_1$$
$$\mu_2(T) \approx \bar{\mu_2}(T=T_0)+ \frac{d \bar{\mu_2}}{dT} \cdot (T-T_0) + e\Phi_1$$

so there is an extra term in the contact potential related to the difference of $\frac{d \bar{\mu}}{dT}$ of both metals, so the Seebeck coefficient for a metal would be just (this is most likely wrong...)

$$S  \approx \frac{1}{e} \frac{d \bar{\mu}}{dT} $$

But I hardly believe, that this is the case, because fermi level does not enough depend on temperature to explain measured Seebeck effects.

What would be the right way and **why** my generalization is not valid anymore?
I know, that Seebeck coefficient is somehow related to conductivity, but conductivity can surely not be derived by such simple consideration.
Is it possible at all to relate Seebeck coefficient simply to fermi level or chemical potential? I guess that my "derivation" is wrong, but why? is it because there is no thermal equilibrium when we have two different temperatures and therefore I cannot argue in the same way?

Life seems be too short to understand that all...

Comment: I don’t have a complete answer, but Seebeck coefficient is related to the details of the band structure. So, you would at the very least need to consider the density of states as well.

Comment: But for a given density of states g(E) the condition to be satisfied is $\int_0^\infty g(E) \frac{1}{1+e^{(E-\mu)/k_BT}} dE = n$ and therefore the chemical potential $\mu$ is at least theoretically defined. My idea was, that the change of $\mu$ with respect to T is the Seebeck-Coefficient. Is this assumption fundamentally wrong?

Comment: I really like your question, something to ponder on. As far as I,remeber, the seebeck coeff is related to the curvature of.the fermi surface, not how blurry it might be due to temperature. So i guess your derivation does not deal with the seebeck effect but i would have to think with a sheet of paper and a pencil to figure things out. Note.that the seebeck effect exists in a single material too, as long as there is a non vanishing delta T across it.